# problems with options to xdotool

Tags: c, xdotool

The xdotool man page lists some options that iv'e tried to use and gt error messages from. For example, `xdotool --sync mousemove 100 100`
gives:

```
xdotool: unrecognized option '--sync'
Usage: xdotool <cmd> <args>
```

Another example `xdotool --window <window_id> type "Hello world"`
gives:

```
xdotool: unrecognized option '--window'
Usage: xdotool <cmd> <args>

xdotool version 3.20160805.1
```

I looked at the source code and those are both listed as valid options, but I don't think the code is doing the right thing...

in the source file cmd_mousemove.c:

```c
  int cmd_mousemove(context_t *context) {
  int ret = 0;
  char *cmd = *context->argv;
  char *window_arg = NULL;

  struct mousemove mousemove;
  mousemove.clear_modifiers = 0;
  mousemove.polar_coordinates = 0;
  mousemove.opsync = 0;
  mousemove.screen = 0;
  mousemove.x = 0;
  mousemove.y = 0;
  mousemove.step = 0;

  int c;
  typedef enum {
    opt_unused, opt_help, opt_sync, opt_clearmodifiers, opt_polar,
    opt_screen, opt_step, opt_delay, opt_window
  } optlist_t;
  static struct option longopts[] = {
    { "clearmodifiers", no_argument, NULL, opt_clearmodifiers },
    { "help", no_argument, NULL, opt_help},
    { "polar", no_argument, NULL, opt_polar },
    { "screen", required_argument, NULL, opt_screen },
    //{ "step", required_argument, NULL, opt_step },
    { "sync", no_argument, NULL, opt_sync },
    //{ "delay", required_argument, NULL, opt_delay },
    { "window", required_argument, NULL, opt_window },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  };
  static const char *usage = 
      "Usage: %s [options] <x> <y>\n"
      "-c, --clearmodifiers      - reset active modifiers (alt, etc) while typing\n"
      //"-d, --delay <MS>          - sleeptime in milliseconds between steps.\n"
      //"--step <STEP>             - pixels to move each time along path to x,y.\n" "-p, --polar               - Use polar coordinates. X as an angle, Y as distance\n"
      "--screen SCREEN           - which screen to move on, default is current screen\n"
      "--sync                    - only exit once the mouse has moved\n"
      "-w, --window <windowid>   - specify a window to move relative to.\n";
  int option_index;

  while ((c = getopt_long_only(context->argc, context->argv, "+chw:pd:",
                               longopts, &option_index)) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
      case 'c':
      case opt_clearmodifiers:
        mousemove.clear_modifiers = 1;
        break;
      case 'h':
      case opt_help:
        printf(usage, cmd);
        consume_args(context, context->argc);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        break;
      case opt_screen:
        mousemove.screen = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      case 'w':
      case opt_window:
        window_arg = strdup(optarg);
        break;
      case 'p':
      case opt_polar:
        mousemove.polar_coordinates = 1;
        break;
      case opt_step:
        mousemove.step = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      case 'd':
      case opt_delay:
        mousemove.delay = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 0) * 1000;
        break;
      case opt_sync:
        mousemove.opsync = 1;
        break;
      default:
        printf("unknown opt: %d\n", c);
        fprintf(stderr, usage, cmd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
```

Reading the man page for `getopt_long_only()`, am I wrong in thinking that the 3rd argument is not correct for all the options listed?  Specifically, it doesn't list 's' as an option and even if it did, how would it distinguish 'sync' from 'screen' ?

Comment: Why would it need to list 's' as an option?

Comment: well looking at the options it does list, it looks like they are using the first character of the long option name... that is my guess... i dunno I haven't done any C coding in awhile and I'm not that familiar with the getopts() calls.

Comment: Then maybe you should look up what getopt returns, instead of just assuming that it does the wrong thing. It's much more sensible to assume that it does the *right* thing because otherwise nobody would be using this software because it wouldn't work.

Comment: My analysis may be inaccurate, but the man page lists --sync and --window as valid options.  When I use them as the man page suggests and get error messages instead, somethiing is wrong.  If they are not valid options, as the code suggests, then the manpage should be corrected.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a really old version of xdotool installed? Or that --sync has to be *after* mousemove?

Answer (score 0):

> in the source file cmd_mousemove.c:

Yes, it's an option to `mousemove` like a "sub"-command, not to `xdotool`.

```
xdotool mousemove --sync 100 100
```

Xdotool has syntax `cmd args...` - first command, then arguments *to that command*. Different commands every parses separately, and when one is done, the next command is detected again. It's so that you can chain commands:

```
xdotool mousemove --sync 100 100 type --window <windowid> "Hello world"
```

Typically with `xdotool`, you first set "current active window" and then do modifications on that window, so it's `xdotool getactivewindow dosomething` or `xdotool search --options_to_serach dosomething`. Like from documentation:

```
xdotool search --class xterm -- windowsize --usehints %@ 80 24
        |------------------|                          ^^ - uses ative window
        cmd    args...
                                |----------------------------|
                                cmd        args...
```

or:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0
```

See the sections `WINDOW STACK` and `COMMAND CHAINING` in `man xdotool` for more info.